# Hide/show image using autolayout?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes, ios-autolayout

I have an image of a little character that I want to remove on 3.5 screen[image: this guy]. The value selector only offers 3.5, 4 and 4.7. I want only 3.5! Does this have to be done programmatically.[image: I want only 3.5]

Answer (score 0):

override updateConstraint method inside your viewcontroller

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    //do something here with the constraint
    self.yourconstraint.constant = ?

    //or you can inactive a constraint
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([yourConstraint])

    //then you can put logic here : where your screen size 320
    if (Screen.size.width == 320) {
       //update your constraint
    }
    super.updateContraint()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, Id love a non programmatic solution as I'm a designer. I'll pass this on to the dev team.

Comment: you can also change the auto layout priority, but it should be little tricky,